# Sending Gmail notifications from my iOS/android app

Tags: android, ios, gmail

For a feature of my iOS/android app, I want to send Gmail notifications and automatically disable Gmail notifications from the Gmail app. Is this possible using the Gmail api (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api)? If not, is it possible using another method?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing GMail with Firebase Push Notifications (formerly named Google Cloud Messaging GCM)?

Comment: I'm referring to Gmail email notifications that pop up on your phone.

Comment: Gmail is an Email system, so notifications occur for mails. I don't think that Google expected someone who wants to send or suppress new mail notifications in their Gmail app.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear- I want my app to send email notifications to the user (at the very minimum). It would be a benefit to have notifications from the Gmail app automatically disabled so that my app wouldn't need to tell the user to disable it themselves (because the user wouldn't want the same email notifications from both my app and the Gmail app).